# Object.create setting __proto__ but not prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm pretty new to using object.create instead of the classical js way to acheive prototypical inheritance.

In Chrome at least I was surprised to see the following code:

```
var baseObject = {
test : function(){
    console.log('Child');
}
}

var newObject = Object.create(baseObject);
newObject.test = function(){
console.log('Parent');
this.__proto__.test();
}
console.log(newObject);

newObject.test();
```

Produces this (simulating the output in web tools):

```
Object {test: function, test: function} 
    test: function (){
    __proto__: Object
        test: function (){
        __proto__: Object
Parent
Child
```

So you see it's not setting prototype but instead only "__proto__", which I thought was discouraged in its use. You can see that in my code I'm able to properly inherit, and call the parent object, but only using "__proto__". Using "prototype" results in an error (undefined).

What's going on here? I figured object.create would set the "prototype" instead as that is the standard (or so I had assumed). Why is it populating and making me using "__proto__"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No using `__proto__` to set up your prototypal inheritance is discouraged because it's non-standard. That doesn't mean you can't use `Object.create()` to make a new object with a particular prototype object.

Objects do not have a `.prototype` property by default. You're confusing the `.prototype` object of a function.

So if I have a function like this:

```
function Foo() {

}
```

That `Foo` function object has a `.prototype` property that references an object that will be used as the `__proto__` of any objects created when invoked as a constructor.

```
var f = new Foo();
```

So now `f` is an object with the `Foo.prototype` in its prototype chain. You can verify this using `Object.getPrototypeOf()`;

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(f) === Foo.prototype; // true
```

---

What `Object.create` gives you is the ability to set up the same prototype chain, but without using a constructor function. So this would be equivalent.

```
var f2 = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
```

Now we have an object that is set up in the same manner as the original `f` object.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(f2) === Foo.prototype;            // true
Object.getPrototypeOf(f2) === Object.getPrototypeOf(f); // true
```

---

So it's just a different way of doing what is ultimately the same thing. The relationship between an object and its prototype chain is an *internal* relationship. The non-standard `__proto__` just exposes that relationship.

Comment: Very interesting. You are right I forgot prototype only applied to functions. So essentially, at least chrome, the use of __proto__ kind of replicates prototype for plan objects in a non-standard way?

Comment: @nahelm: Sort of. The `__proto__` lets you give an existing object a new prototype chain. The constructor functions and `Object.create` just let you set it up at the time the object is created. From there it's permanent. In fact, if you create an object from the constructor function, then you give the constructor function a new `.prototype` object, the object you already created will still reference the original. It never changes.

Comment: I think I'm finally getting it. Part of my confusion was that I had expected my web tools in chrome to show the prototype of the object I was creating. I also thought for some silly reason that using the new keyword allows you to use the prototype keyword (f.prototype in your example), which is not true. When I did your Foo example and added a function to it's prototype, that function also shows up in the __proto__ object when I console.log(f). So essentially __proto__ in this case exposes the prototype chain which is normally hidden and as you said permanent.

Comment: @nahelm: Yep, exactly. It's a little bit unfortunate that JavaScript originally used these constructor functions to set up the prototype chain. It's really pretty confusing. The key part to understand is that prototypal inheritance is all about that hidden link between objects that is used when looking up properties. `Object.create()` is a more direct way of creating that link. `Object.getPrototypeOf()` lets you fetch the next object in the chain, and `__proto__` lets you fetch or replace it.

Answer (score 0):

An instance's `__proto__` property should be the same as the *constructor's* `prototype` property.

> When an object is created, its `__proto__` property is set to reference the same object as its internal `[[Prototype]]` (i.e. its constructor's `prototype` object).  Assigning a new value to `__proto__` also changes the value of the internal `[[Prototype]]` property, except where the object is non–extensible.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto#Description

Comment: In this case though, since the original object was an object, the constructor's prototype was object. As a result `constructor.prototype != __proto__`.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.create()` sets the prototype for that particular object instance.  `prototype` is a property on a constructor function that is the object *automatically* assigned as the [[Prototype]] for each instance created by using the `new` operator with that constructor function.

`__proto__` is a non-standard way to access the [[Prototype]] for a particular instance.  You can also call [Object.getPrototypeOf(this)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) for a standard way to access the prototype.

Comment: Might want to change "prototype" to `[[Prototype]]` to clarify when you're talking about the internal property.